# Java Swing, Booleans and textfields

Tags: java, swing

this is my current code for a project I am doing. At the moment I am trying to match values to the textFields, that are produced when certain buttons are pressed. For example, When you click Start train, the Doors open will change to Closed, train ready will change to Yes, "train on" will change to yes and train moving will be changed to No. I am very new to java swing.

I have attempted to do this using Boolean values and If statements to produce the message if the value is true or false. I have then connected the trainPowerField, trainMovingField, trainDoorsField and trainReadyField to the textFields by putting it as the values for the textFields. 
But the problem i get now is:

FirstFrame.java:120: error: no suitable constructor found for JTextField(boolean)
                        bottomRight.add(trainReady = new JTextField (trainReadyField));

For each textField.

I don't understand how i don't have suitable constructors? 
I also know I have made this more complicated than i should have, but don't understand any other way to do it.

Edit*
Had to remove code for uni reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `JTextField` constructor that takes a single `boolean` argument and it doesn't now that you want to convert it to a `String` value. You need to do it explicitly. Try using

```
new JTextField(Boolean.toString(trainReadyField));
```

You'll need to do the same thing for the other `boolean` values (`trainPowerField`, etc.).

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. What would you suggest i change my if statements too? As the problem i get now is those system line prints, stay the same. Do i need a sort of clear before i press the different buttons?

Comment: @Mentoos - I didn't notice those before and if you're using an IDE, I'm surprised you didn't receive a warning. The problem with those is that you are using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equality operator (`==`). As a result, every time each `if` statement executes, it sets the corresponding field back to `true`. I suggest you use `if (trainPowerField) { ... }`, etc. (You can use the boolean value itself, rather than comparing it to `true`. If you feel more comfortable with an explicit equality test, use `if (trainPowerField == true) { ... }` (with `==` instead of `=`).)

Comment: Ye I'm having to write it out by hand without the use of an IDE.

Comment: @Mentoos - Well, just get rid of the `= true` in each `if` statement test and it should work much better (or change it to `== true`, but that's not considered good style for testing boolean values).

Comment: The best way you would suggest is, using the Boolean value itself? I'm not too sure how, so it's why i feel more comfortable with using equality. Though the problem i get now is only false is printed in the textFields, and they don't change. Will using your method change that?

Comment: @Mentoos - I recommend changing the `if` statements to use the boolean value directly (`if (trainReadyField) { ... }`, etc.) It means **exactly** the same thing as `if (trainReadyField == true) { ... }`. The important thing is to avoid accidentally assigning `true` when all you want to do is test the value. If it only prints false now, then you have a logic error somewhere in your code. Just track down what's happening and you should be able to find it.

Comment: I attempted to use .setText instead of println as i thought this would correct the mistake. But i get told i cant dereference a boolean? Though i converted the boolean to a string? I amended the code if it's easier to see.

Comment: @Mentoos - Perhaps you meant to write `trainPower.setText("on");`? The UI element is `trainPower`, not `trainPowerField`.

Comment: Nvm, decided to scrap Booleans, and just used strings. It works as i wanted it too now.

Answer (score 1):

The `JTextField` constructor is expecting a string, not a boolean, try the following for all of them:

```
new JTextField(Boolean.toString(trainReadyField))
```

or you can even write your own "toString" like conversion:

```
new JTextField(trainReadyField? "T" : "F"))
```

for better code maintainability, you should write your own function

```
public static String boolToText(boolean b) {
   if (b) return "T";
   return "F";
}
```

Comment: Making the method `boolToText` static is probably a good idea. Also typo "Feild".

Comment: Actually, since `trainReadyField` is of the primitive type `boolean` not the class `Boolean`, `trainReadyField.toString()` doesn't compile. You need to put `new Boolean(trainReadyField).toString()`, or do it as Ted Hopp did.

Comment: Thank you :) I forgot about conversion, cause I'm thinking too much of the new features swing brings.